# DataTable Sorting Issue (Instead of 1st row taking 2nd row for sorting)

Tags: datatables

I have a dataTable and it has two rows in table header. One row is the column names while the other one is the input fields

I dont know but by default the sorting is being done on the input fields (2nd row) rather that the label fields (1st row)

My code for the datatable is

```
$('#result-table').DataTable({
  "paging": true,
  "lengthChange": false,
  "searching": true,
  "ordering": true,
  "info": true,
  "autoWidth": false,
  "responsive": true,
  
});
```

I am cloning the header row and adding the input field as

```
$("#result-table thead tr").clone(true).appendTo("#result-table thead");


// add a text input filter to each column of the new row
  $("#result-table thead tr:eq(1) th").each(function (i) {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html("<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Search '" + title + "' />");
    $("input", this).on( "keyup change", function () {
      if ($("#result-table").DataTable().column(i).search() !== this.value) {
        $("#result-table").DataTable().column(i).search(this.value).draw();
      }
    });
  });
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 things you need to make sure you are doing:

1. Make sure the `clone()` code and the code to create input fields is placed inside the `$(document).ready(function()` code - but it must be placed *before* the `$('#result-table').DataTable({...})` code.
2. Make sure your DataTables initialization includes this option:

```
orderCellsTop: true,
```

You may already be doing (1) - but (2) is missing from the code in the question.